# Linq map table to list<int>

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am using c# and Enterprise Library to retrieve data from Store Procedure.

I am using Linq to map Table to Entity like this.

```
List<ActivitySearchEntity> result = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
    .Tables[0]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList()
    .ConvertAll(dr => new ActivitySearchEntity
    {
        Activity_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Activity_ID"].ToString()),
        User_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["User_ID"].ToString())
    });
```

It Works fine...

when I map to entity it works fine, what I need is to mapp to a `List<int>`

```
List<ActivitySearchEntity> result = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
    .Tables[0]
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList<int>()
```

or something like this.. but it does not work.

How can I map to an `List<int>`?

Comment: When you say doesn't work - what do you get?

Comment: You cannot implicitly convert from `List<int>` to `List<ActivitySearchEntity>`. You should declare `result` as `List<int>` instead

Comment: There is no point in doing a `AsEnumerable` before a `ToList`.  Also a `ToList` will not transform the data, you can only do that with a `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what your command you will have different problems:

1. If it is the same command like the first snippet then your table contains more than a single field. Therefore it cannot "implicitly" be converted to a `List<int>`. You need to add a `.Select` to select just that one field ( + the parsing to `int` as in your first snippet.

   ```
   db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand)
       .Tables[0]
       .AsEnumerable()
       .Select(dr => Convert.ToInt32(dr["Activity_ID"].ToString()).ToList();
   ```
2. Suppose your command retrieves only one column and it is of type `int` your variable is of type `List<ActivitySearchEntity>` and not `List<int>`. Change it to the latter